# Create post screen-react native application

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am working on blog mobile application using react native cli quickstart and nodeJS. I have problem when it comes to create new post and when I take picture with camera. Here is my frontend and backend code for create post screen:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, PermissionsAndroid, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';


const CreatePostScreen = ({route}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState(null); // State to store the selected image path
  /*const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);*/
  const { userId } = route.params;
  const handleCreatePost = async () => {
    try {
      if (!imagePath) {
        console.error('Image path is not set.');
        return;
      }

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('title', title);
      formData.append('content', content);
      formData.append('image', {
        uri: imagePath,
        type: 'image/jpg', // Adjust the image type as needed
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
      console.log(formData)

      const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.132:9000/api/post/create', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });

      navigation.navigate('AllPosts', { userRole: 'admin', userId });
      console.log('Post created:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating post:', error);
    }
  };

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    console.log('launchCamera');
  
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: 'App Camera Permission',
          message: 'App needs access to your camera',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      );
  
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('Camera permission given');
        const options = {
          mediaType: 'photo', // Specify media type (photo or video)
          quality: 0.5, // Image quality (0 to 1)
        };
  
        // Open the camera
        ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
          if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('Image picker error:', response.error);
          } else {
            // Set the selected image data in the state
            //console.log(response.assets[0].uri);
            setImagePath(response.assets[0].uri);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>Create Post</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Title"
        value={title}
        onChangeText={(text) => setTitle(text)}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Content"
        multiline
        value={content}
        onChangeText={(text) => setContent(text)}
        style={styles.input}
      />
       {/* Display the selected image */}
       {imagePath && (
        <Image source={{ uri: imagePath }} style={styles.imagePreview} />
      )}

    {/* Button to open the camera */}
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePhoto} style={styles.chooseImageButton}>
      <Text style={styles.chooseImageText}>Take a Photo</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        
          <Button title="Create Post" onPress={handleCreatePost} />
        
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 16,
    padding: 8,
  },
  imagePreview: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  chooseImageButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  chooseImageText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: 16,
  },
});

export default CreatePostScreen;
```

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { title, content } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)
    const imagePath = req.file.path; // Multer stores the file path in req.file.path
    console.log(imagePath)
  
    try {
      // Create the post with the image path
      const post = await Post.create({
        title,
        content,
        postedBy: req.user._id,
        name: req.user.name,
        image: imagePath, // Store the image path in the database
      });
  
      console.log(post.image);
      res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        post,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating post:', error);
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

Also multer configuration:

```
const multer = require('multer');


//create post

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, './uploads/'); // Define the destination folder for uploaded files
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    },
  });
  
  const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // Define allowed file types (e.g., JPEG and PNG)
    if (
      file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ||
      file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
      file.mimetype === 'image/jpg'
    ) {
      cb(null, true); // Accept the file
    } else {
      cb(null, false); // Reject the file
    }
  };
  
  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5, // Limit file size to 5MB
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
  });
//blog routes
router.post('/post/create',isAuthenticated,upload.single('image'),createPost);
```

Whenever I click create post I get Error creating post: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500]. Also, in database I am saving image as type string. Please if someone could clear this for me would be very thankful.

Comment: Your server is crashing. Try wrapping the code in try/catch and log the error.

Comment: Again I get same error text